# "Hidden" axiom of choice?

Tags: measure-theory, axiom-of-choice, filters

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $S$ such that:

- $\mu\left(\emptyset\right)=0$ and $\mu(S)=1$
- if $X\subseteq Y$, then $\mu(X)\leq\mu(Y)$
- $\mu\left(\{a\}\right)=0$ for all $a\in S$
- if $X_n$, $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, are pairwise disjoint, then $\displaystyle\mu\left(\bigcup \limits_{n=0}^\infty X_n\right)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\mu(X_n)$
- $\mu$ is two-valued, i.e. $\mu(X)=1$ or $\mu(X)=0$ for all $X$

Let $U=\{X\subseteq S\colon\mu(X)=1\}$. $U$ is a non principal ultrafilter on $S$, and this implies a weaker axiom of choice.

I'm not sure where I used it, but I guess it's in that measure. Can you show me an example of such a measure? Alternatively, can you tell me where I need $\sf AC$ if it's not in the measure?

Edit: Let $S$ be uncountable and $\mu\left(X\right)=0$ if $X$ is finite or countable. It seems to me that this measure can be construct without any assumption about $\sf AC$. And this leads to a nonprincipal ultrafilter, which in fact does require some weak form of $\sf AC$? I still don't understand..

Comment: "Let $\mu$ be..." presupposes a $\mu$ satisfying those properties exists, which does indeed rely on AC.

Comment: To use the $\sf AC$ you need a proof or a reasoning of some sorts, there is none here.

Comment: I'm sorry, this example came from Jech's _Set theory_ pages 125-126. I just want to know why does this construction rely on AC since I can't see it.

Comment: @izabera: Your construction of a nonprincipal ultrafilter doesn't rely on the AC: you have correctly provided a construction independent of the AC that turns such a $\mu$ into a nonprincipal ultrafilter. What you *haven't* done is try to construct $\mu$, or show such a thing exists.

Comment: Is your measure defined on all subsets of $S$? Such a measure could't even be shown to exist with the axiom of choice.

Comment: What sort of weak version of the axiom of choice do you expect to prove from this? What is the quantifier on the set $S$?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker This measure is not translation invariant.

Comment: @izabera I did not write "can be shown not to exist". A measure of this kind must be defined on the powerset of a *measurable cardinal*. The existence of such a cardinal is widely believed to be consistent, but a relative consistency proof is not possible. Look [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136134/do-measurable-cardinals-exist-assuming-zfc).

Comment: The notion of translation requires $S$ to be a group to begin with. Is it a group?

Comment: The filter of co-finite sets [given in the Edit] doesn't need AC-- it's the existence of an ultrafilter (in which EVERY set is measuarable), extending that filter which needs (some weakened version of) AC. I assume "for all X" in the last bullet means "all subsets X of S."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how such a $\mu$ would be created.  We know its value for finite sets.  Now we go through the infinite sets on at a time.  The first set is $A$.  Decide $\mu(A) = 1$.  Then necessarily $\mu(A^c) = 0$.  Now go to the next set, call it $B$.  If $B$ is in the sigma algebra generated by the finite sets and $A$, then the value is known.  Otherwise set $\mu(B) = 1$, and look at the next infinite set.

You will have to make these choices again and again.  In fact you will have to make these choices a transfinite number of times.  Since you have to make infinitely many choices, the axiom of choice has to be invoked.

Is it possible that there exists a clever argument to find a $\mu$ in a more constructive manner?  The only way to show this cannot be done is to prove there exists models of set theory in which such a $\mu$ doesn't exist.  And I believe that this has been done.

Comment: You probably must emphasize that you are not giving a proof that choice is used to build $\mu$, only an intuitive argument.

Comment: That is what I was trying to say with my last paragraph.  I'll slightly edit it to make it clearer?

Comment: One issue here is that your description already uses a well-ordering of $\mathcal P(S)$, but the existence of a non-principal ultrafilter on $S$ is strictly weaker, so your conclusion is flawed: there are other ways of "building" $\mu$, and these ways are more "constructive" than you suggest.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I thought that the existence of a non-principle ultrafilter was independent of ZF.  What are the "more constructive" ways of making non-principle ultrafilters?  I guess I thought it was just an axiom that you could use instead of AC, that happens to be strictly weaker.

Comment: What I mean is; The axiom of choice is strictly stronger than the statement that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ can be well-ordered, which is strictly stronger than the statement that there is a non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$, which is still not provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$. Of course, we can interpolate many more statements in this list.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I edited the question, is that example constructive enough?

Comment: It doesn't work.  Think about $X_1$ and $X_2$ being two disjoint uncountable sets.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith The measure is $0$ if the set is finite or countable, but it may be $0$ in other cases too...

Comment: To construct the measure, you have to specify which sets have measure zero and which have measure one.  You haven't defined the measure, because if I give you any set which is uncountable and whose complement is uncountable, then there is no way I can tell from your definition what its measure is.

Comment: Yeah I kinda realized that's where it requires a "choice"